# Learn C the Hard Way Exercise 2

Tags: makefile

I just started Learn C the Hard Way and I'm on Exercise #2.

link here:
http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html

The instructions are to make a file with only this in it:

```
    CFLAGS=-Wall -g

    clean:
       rm -f ex1
```

So I created and saved that as Makefile.c, however, upon running it as specified in my compiler (MINGW), I'm getting this error:

```
$make clean
cc    makefile.c    -o makefile
makefile.c:3:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
makefile.c:3:9: error: 'Wall' undeclared here (not in a function)
makefile.c:3:15: error: 'g' undeclared here (not in a function)
makefile.c:5:1: error expected ',' or ';' before 'clean'
cc    Makefile.c    -o Makefile
Makefile.c:3:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
Makefile.c:3:9: error: 'Wall' undeclared here (not in a function)
Makefile.c:3:15: error: 'g' undeclared here (not in a function)
Makefile.c:5:1: error expected ',' or ';' before 'clean'
make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'. Stop.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and/or how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Late, but your makefile should just be named "Makefile"

Makefile is not the source code for a C program, but a set of instructions for the Makefile tool, which gets used when you type "make foo".

Answer (score 1):

Makefile can be called "makefile" or "Makefile"

According to man make:

> "Normally you should call your makefile either makefile or Makefile.  (We recommend Makefile because it appears prominently near the beginning of a directory  listing, right near other important files such as README.)  The first name checked, GNUmakefile, is not recommended for most makefiles."

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tab characters instead of space?  The web page has spaces, but a makefile needs tabs.  Note the author's comment after the makefile code.